# iOS Web Inspector doesn't log Object types

Tags: ios, reactjs, remote-debugging, devtools

I'm using 'remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter' on Windows for debugging react app on iPhone.
My phone can connect to Chrome DevTools correctly and everything goes well until I want to log an Object. It shows [Object, Object] in DevTools console, although I can log string type data. On the other hand, I can log everything on my laptop chrome browser as well.
In addition, console.log() doesn't show anything on DevTools console and I had to change them to console.info() in my code (still everything works on Windows Chrome).

On my Windows Chrome:

[image]

On 'remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter' DevTools:

[image]

Comment: Why not just `console.log(JSON.stringify(yourObject))`?

Comment: It's not clear to debug a large object.

Comment: but its also easy to copy and then paste it whereever you'd like. maybe a json viewer, or even just right there in the console `const myObj = JSON.parse(<pasted content>)`

Comment: When I log my Object it errors "TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.".